# Storing Foreign Key values from 2 tables Laravel

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I have 3 models - user, order & retailer
I have created a form for the user to make an order. 
The order form has two select boxes.
first one is select user which has all the user IDs
the second is select retailer which has all the retailer IDs
I then have a textbox to enter amount of the order.

On submitting the form i get the following error. 
    SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or    update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`shop`.`orders`, CONSTRAINT `orders_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `orders` (`total`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (10, 2017-03-06 10:22:43, 2017-03-06 10:22:43))

Can someone help me understand how i can store the foreign key values from the Users table, Retailers table into the Orders table?

my store method:

```
$data = \Input::only("name", "retailer", "total");
    $order = new Order($data);
    $order->save();
    return redirect("orders");
```

The create order form:

```
{!! Form::open(array("url"=>"orders", "class"=>"form-horizontal")) !!}

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label("name", "Select User", array("class"=>"col-md-2")) !!}
        <div class="col-md-10"> 
        {!! Form::select('id', $users, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label("retailer", "Select Retailer", array("class"=>"col-md-2")) !!}
        <div class="col-md-10"> 
        {!! Form::select('id', $retailers, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label("total", "Enter total", array("class"=>"col-md-2")) !!}
        <div class="col-md-10"> 
        {!! Form::text("total","",array("placeholder"=>"Enter total", "class="=>"form-control")) !!}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2"> {!! Form::submit('Order', array("class"=>"btn btn-primary","id"=>"btn")) !!} </div>
        <div class="col-md-10"><a href="{{url('/orders')}}" class="btn btn-success">Back..</a></div>
    </div>


    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use relationship or add user ID manually. For example, if you want to make current user related to the order:

```
$order = new Order($data);
$order->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
$order->save();
```

Comment: How would i then handle storing retailerId into the orders table which is a foreign key from retailers table?

Comment: @Jay240692 you didn't provide any retailers related code. If you have `retailer_id` in the `orders` table, you can fill it manually like you did with `user_id`

Comment: Fantastic - that worked! i added         $order->retailerId = $request->get('id');